# Clementine and other Qt-based apps crash when click file manager window

Tags: qt, clementine

I have a problem while play music on Clementine on Ubuntu 12.04 64 bit.
It is crash when I click the file manager window on the right side.
Anyone has idea?

Basically this happens with a lot of Qt-based apps (qtractor, lmms, ...)

Answer (score 4):

Looks like a typo; it should be

```
sudo apt-get remove qt-at-spi
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution --> just remove qt-apt-spi using command line:

```
sudo apt-get remove qt-apt-spi
```

Comment: What's this?
`E: Unable to locate package qt-apt-spi`